# X be a set, $\sum$ be any $\sigma$- algebra on X, is there a measure on X such that every element of $\sigma$- algebra is measurable?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

In particular, on $\mathbb{R}$, $2^{\mathbb{R}}$ be a $\sigma$- algebra, is there a measure on $\mathbb{R}$ such that every element of $2^{\mathbb{R}}$ is measurable?

Comment: The measure that count the element of a set.

Comment: How about the measure that assigns $0$ to every set ?

Comment: It is more interesting to note that there is no non-trivial translation-invariant sigma-finite measure on $(\mathbb R, 2^{\mathbb R})$, see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1544458/proving-that-theres-no-translation-invariant-measure-on-the-power-set-of-math).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pick any $x \in X$ and define $\mu(A)=1$ if $x \in A$, $\mu(A)=0$ for $x \notin A$. This is a measure and every set is measurable. This works for any set and any sigma algebra on it.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a complete answer, but only treats the case mentioned in the body of your question.

---

Yes.

E.g. let the measure be prescribed by $A\mapsto|A|$ if $A$ is finite and $A\mapsto+\infty$ otherwise.

There are more (see the comment of Gabriel on your question).